# Its asking everytime in Iphone to enable cookies?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Docusign rest API in our application.
When view the application in IPhone or Ipad its asking to enable cookies. Do we need enable cookies? Its asking every time when docusign page is coming.

Is there a way to get rid of this? Please help on this?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: If the Docusign API is requesting cookies, and it needs cookies to operate, then you need to enable cookies. (I've never worked with Docusign, but from what you've said, yes you need cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Yes unfortunately you need to enable cookies for signing.  This has been a feature request that we've seen in the past and I believe DocuSign is actually working on cookie-less signing at the moment; however that's all the info I have on that.  Looks like you'll need to enable cookies on your mobile devices.